# Gradle set outputDir of java classes

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, build.gradle, source-sets

Here I have a sourceset of java file in 'src/main/java', I want to post the classFiles generated to the outputDir mentioned, but I GET AN ERROR.

```
Could not find method outputDir() for arguments [src/main] on root project
```

Here is the snippet from build.gradle

```
sourceSets {
    main.java {
       srcDir 'src/main/java'
        outputDir 'src/main'
    }
}
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to dump the classes into the source folder?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the docs on [SourceSetOutput Guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput.html) & [SourceSetOutput API Doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/SourceSetOutput.html), as it provides the details required to set an alternative output directory

Per the example there and for you code, I'd suggest trying with

```
outputDir = dir('src/main')
```

This makes sense with the error you've received as outputDir is a property and not a method, the way you wrote it is a method invocation.

Though it can only be determined by knowing the exact Gradle version you're using

Answer (score 0):

`outputDir` needs to be a (groovy) File, not a String ([see docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput.html)).

You can simply wrap your String path with `file(..)`.

This should work:

```
sourceSets {
    main.java {
       srcDir 'src/main/java'
       outputDir file('src/main')
    }
}
```